# Initialize Map with array in Typescript: new Map([[k1, v1], [k2, v2]])

Tags: typescript

These two initializations should not be equivalent?

This works ok:

```
private screensMap: Map<string, ComponentType<any>>;

public constructor() {
    this.screensMap = new Map()
        .set(BootstrapLaunch.name, BootstrapLaunch)
        .set(BootstrapWelcome.name, BootstrapWelcome);
}
```

But this fail:

```
private screensMap: Map<string, ComponentType<any>>;

public constructor() {
    this.screensMap = new Map([
        [BootstrapLaunch.name, BootstrapLaunch],
        [BootstrapWelcome.name, BootstrapWelcome],
    ]);
}
```

With next error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '([string, typeof BootstrapLaunch] | [string, typeof BootstrapWelcome])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadonlyArray<[string, typeof BootstrapLaunch]>'.
  Type '[string, typeof BootstrapLaunch] | [string, typeof BootstrapWelcome]' is not assignable to type '[string, typeof BootstrapLaunch]'.
    Type '[string, typeof BootstrapWelcome]' is not assignable to type '[string, typeof BootstrapLaunch]'.
      Type 'typeof BootstrapWelcome' is not assignable to type 'typeof BootstrapLaunch'.
        Type 'BootstrapWelcome' is not assignable to type 'BootstrapLaunch'.
          Types of property 'componentDidMount' are incompatible.
            Type '(() => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
              Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
```

Is it a Typescript bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like a TypeScript bug to me, not being able to find a common supertype for `typeof BootstrapWelcome` and `typeof BootstrapLaunch`. Try casting them to `ComponentType<any>` explicitly.

Comment: Using explicit casting  to `ComponentType<any>` it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is trying to infer the type of your values, but since your components are different in terms of implementing `componentDidMount`, it's trying to warn you about a possible programming mistake.

Since the desired type for your values is broader than the type of the provided components, you can use type parameters to tell TypeScript what your intention is:

```
public constructor() {
    this.screensMap = new Map<string, ComponentType<any>>([
        [BootstrapLaunch.name, BootstrapLaunch],
        [BootstrapWelcome.name, BootstrapWelcome],
    ]);
}
```